# Get YouTube video height via API

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube-api, jsonp

How can I get video height, for ex. like the height shown in `Stats for nerds` ? The video may be 1920px in width but height can be smaller than 1080px and I want to get that height by `ajax` or `API`

[image: kida, o'najr]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple way is to use the oembed

Example http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DbDOYN-6gdRE&format=json then the jason gives you

```
{"height": 344, "title": "Auto-Tune the News #8: dragons. geese. Michael Vick. (ft. T-Pain)", "author_url": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/user\/schmoyoho", "thumbnail_height": 360, "version": "1.0", "provider_url": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/", "type": "video", "width": 459, "provider_name": "YouTube", "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/bDOYN-6gdRE\/hqdefault.jpg", "thumbnail_width": 480, "html": "\u003ciframe width=\"459\" height=\"344\" src=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/bDOYN-6gdRE?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen\u003e\u003c\/iframe\u003e", "author_name": "schmoyoho"}
```

More info http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/10/oembed-support.html

or

http://oembed.com/#section5

Comment: This doesen't work for all videos.
For ex this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NschES-8e0
The dimensions are 1920 by 844 so the height should be 480 * 844 / 1920 = **211px** but it shows as 270px @ceasar